# How to calculate natural log of determinant involving identity matrix?

Tags: matrices, logarithms, determinant

I have an expression given by $$\ln \left(\text{det}\left(\frac{y^{H}y}{N}\text{I}_{N}\right)\right)$$ where $N$ is a scalar and product of $y^{H}y$ is a matrix. How can I simplify this expression?

Comment: I think that $y^Hy=\|y\|^2$ a scalar, and $I_N$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix, right?

Comment: Yes, $y^{H}y$ is a matrix and $I_{N}$ is $N$ x $N$ identity matrix.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If $y^Hy$ is a matrix then the identity matrix would be superfluous. Furthermore, it would be a rank-one matrix, so its determinant would be zero, and the log would be undefined. Check your sources again, it **_has_** to be a scalar.

Comment: yes, the identity matrix is superfluous. But $y^{H}y$ is matrix with full rank (not rank 1. I had verified from the research paper). The final answer should be $N\text{ln}\frac{y^{H}y}{N}$. I am not getting how determinant is vanished in this expression and also from where $N$ in multiplication is coming.

Comment: The final answer is consistent with the scalar interpretation of $y^Hy\;$

Comment: Ok...but how we get the final answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113421/discussion-between-charu-and-greg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of a scalar multiple of the $n\times n$ identity matrix is
$$\det(\alpha I_n) = \alpha^n\det(I) = \alpha^n$$
and the logarithm is
$$\log\det(\alpha I_n) = n\log(\alpha)$$
Setting $\,\alpha = \frac 1n y^Hy\;$ yields
$$\log\det\left(\frac {y^Hy}{n}\,I_n\right) = n\log\left(\frac {y^Hy}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that determinants are defined only for square matrices. This implies that you can disregard the identity matrix entirely. Another way to see this is the property $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

So, we have $\ln(\det(\frac{y^Hy}{N}))$. Now, you can either multiply out $y^Hy$ or first divide the coefficients of either $y$ or $y^H$ by the scalar $N$. The order of these two steps does not matter.

The next step is computing the determinant. This can only be done if the number of columns of $y^H$ equals the number of rows of $y$; otherwise, it is undefined. The formula is given in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants

After that, if the determinant is greater than zero, you can compute its natural logarithm, and you are done.

Therefore, the result will either be a scalar or undefined.

Comment: yes.... i had reached upto this solution i.e., $\text{ln}(\text{det}(\frac{y^{H}y}{N})$. But the final answer should be $N\text{ln}(\frac{y^{H}y}{N})$. I am not getting how determinant is vanished in this expression.

Comment: Determinants don't just vanish. I would check for a clerical error.